# Why do we use random effects model to consider clustering effect?

Tags: regression, random-effects-model, intuition, effects

It's hard to get a grasp on the intuition on the random effects model.

As I understand, to summarize, we use random effects model when we wanna regard the variable as drawn from a population, rather than put it as a variable with independent value. If the variable has so many groups(or values if you will), putting so many dummy variables to apply that very independent variable reduces the statistical power. I get it until this point.

On the other hand, some articles say you need to consider clustering effect. But I cannot find any link between clustering effect(or nested effect) and regarding a variable drawn from a population(which means I'm not really interested in the very effect of each values of that variable, instead I wanna summarize the variation into single distribution).

It's still hard to draw an intuitive picture in my brain.

Comment: It would be helpful f you could expand on this a bit more as it is currently a bit hard to see what you are asking. Perhaps an example of the sort of scientific problem you are facing would help.

Comment: Here's one way the two concepts are connected. If I say that in my dataset "students are clustered in classrooms" what I often mean is that instead of the students in my dataset being a random sample of a larger population of students, the classrooms in my dataset are a random sample from the population of classrooms, and that the students I have are random samples from within those sampled classrooms, rather than all classrooms. So I  have sampling error at two different levels and so adding a random intercept at the class level is like adding a class level error term.